# Directx 12 - Adapter not supported

Tags: directx-12

I am currently using a nvidia 675M and in directx 11 I was fine running with feature level 11_0

I am following guides for directx 12 and they say I can still create a device with the feature level 11_0 but when I run it says it is not supported

I know 100% I'm using the correct adapter as it says 675m

So just wondered if there is any way around this or another method or if simply I need a new graphics card :(

Answer (score 1):

The NVidia 675M is a "Fermi" GPU which should be supported for DirectX 12 by NVIDIA per [this post](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3711/~/which-nvidia-gpus-will-support-dx12). The initial focus for NVidia's DX12 driver support is their Maxwell and Kepler parts, so check with NVidia for a driver that supports Fermi.

Another issue to keep in mind is that in systems with more than one graphics card, you need to be sure you are in fact picking the right adapter. The [DirectX 12 VS templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) use the following code to achieve this:

```
void DX::DeviceResources::GetAdapter(IDXGIAdapter1** ppAdapter)
{
    *ppAdapter = nullptr;

    ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter1> adapter;
    for (UINT adapterIndex = 0; DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND != m_dxgiFactory->EnumAdapters1(adapterIndex, adapter.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()); ++adapterIndex)
    {
        DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1 desc;
        DX::ThrowIfFailed(adapter->GetDesc1(&desc));

        if (desc.Flags & DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG_SOFTWARE)
        {
            // Don't select the Basic Render Driver adapter.
            continue;
        }

        // Check to see if the adapter supports Direct3D 12, but don't create the actual device yet.
        if (SUCCEEDED(D3D12CreateDevice(adapter.Get(), m_d3dMinFeatureLevel, _uuidof(ID3D12Device), nullptr)))
        {
#ifdef _DEBUG
            WCHAR buff[256] = {};
            swprintf_s(buff, L"Direct3D Adapter (%u): VID:%04X, PID:%04X - %ls\n", adapterIndex, desc.VendorId, desc.DeviceId, desc.Description);
            OutputDebugStringW(buff);
#endif
            break;
        }
    }

#if !defined(NDEBUG)
    if (!adapter)
    {
        // Try WARP12 instead
        if (FAILED(m_dxgiFactory->EnumWarpAdapter(IID_PPV_ARGS(adapter.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()))))
        {
            throw std::exception("WARP12 not available. Enable the 'Graphics Tools' feature-on-demand");
        }

        OutputDebugStringA("Direct3D Adapter - WARP12\n");
    }
#endif

    if (!adapter)
    {
        throw std::exception("No Direct3D 12 device found");
    }

    *ppAdapter = adapter.Detach();
}
```

Comment: Hi chuck Thanks for such a fast reply,I will double check my drivers are up to date and yes I did the loop through to check I'm getting the correct adapter Thank you

Answer (score 0):

NVIDIA have not yet released a driver that supports DX12 on Fermi, so this won't work.

Comment: so as of now it is impossible on this graphics card? guess ill keep on directx 11 gutted as frank luna book comes out next week i wanted to get stuck in :(

Comment: Don't forget the WARP device provides surprisingly good performance. I've not read Frank Luna's book, but I imagine many of the early chapters will not require bleeding edge levels of performance.

Comment: at low resolution, the warp driver is a good enough, but it shows limit fast, reserved resources crash it, and using bindless techniques to pick into an array of texture descriptor crash too. Other bugs are likely to exist.

Comment: OK so just to check as it stands for now with my graphics card I am unable to use directx 12?

Comment: If you have any crashes to report with the WARP driver and can provide details on how to cause the crash, or better yet, a compilable repro, then I can take a look and let my colleagues (at Microsoft) know what's up. And yes, unfortunately there is no DX12 for Fermi right now.

Comment: Ahh well the error shows on the hresult when trying to createdevice simply the system is unsupported I cam get the full error tomorrow when I have my laptop on .  Thanks Adam

Comment: I was referring to the WARP crashes when using Reserved Resources and Bindless techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Initial support for DirectX 12 in Fermi was introduced in the current R384.76, as observed by users on Guru3D [here](http://forums.guru3d.com/showpost.php?p=5447929&postcount=52) and [here](http://forums.guru3d.com/showpost.php?p=5447993&postcount=70), although the driver release notes do not state this.

You may want to run [3DMark Time Spy](http://store.steampowered.com/app/496100/3DMark_Time_Spy_benchmark/) or a similar DirectX 12 workload to confirm this.